# ActionController “No explicit conversion of Symbol into Integer” for new record in Rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeerror, nested-attributes, form-for, actioncontroller

I'm trying to create `@booking` and `@booking.build_passenger` in `form_for` with nested attributes in Rails 4.2.1

The error I get:
[image]

As you see in the console at the bottom of the image:
1. `params.require(:booking)` returns a Hash-like params for `@booking`
2. `params.class` returns `ActionController::Parameters`

As the `params` seems to behave correctly, IMO the problem hides somewhere in the form:

```html
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: params[:flight_id] %>

    <%= render 'flights/flight_info' %>

    <div class="field">
        <b><%= f.label :num_tickets, "Tickets" %></b>  
        <%= f.select(:num_tickets, @num_tickets) %>
    </div><br>
  
    <h4>Passenger info:</h4>
    <%= f.fields_for @booking.build_passenger do |pass| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= pass.label :name %>
            <%= pass.text_field :name %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= pass.label :email %>
            <%= pass.email_field :email %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Book Flight!' %>
<% end %>
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight
  belongs_to :passenger
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passenger
end
```

---

**Question:** Where and how do I have to edit my code for the app to start creating `@booking` instances + `@booking.build_passenger()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `booking_params` needs to be something like:

```
def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, :num_tickets, passenger_attributes: [:id, :name, :email])
end
```

Comment: This is spot on.  Look at it from a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) perspective.  Your adding nested attributes for your  passenger params.  
When adding nested params this way put them as the last argument of the permit() or you will get errors.